# Copy constructor for abstract class

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class

I have an abstract class named `AClass`. In the same package I have `AnotherClass`, in which I have an `ArrayList` of `AClass` objects. In the copy constructor of `AnotherClass` I need to make a duplicate of `AClass` objects inside the `ArrayList`.

The problem:

I cannot create a copy constructor in `AClass` because it is an abstract class and I cannot know the name of the class which will inherit by `AClass`. Actually, in this project, no object will inherit from this class, but this project will be used as a library by other projects which will provide a class child of `AClass`. Is there an error in my design or is there a solution to this problem?

**Edit**: here's some code:

```
public class AnotherClass{
    private ArrayList<AClass> list;
...
    /** Copy constructor
    */
    public AnotherClass(AnotherClass another){
        // copy all fields from "another"
        this.list = new ArrayList<AClass>();
        for(int i = 0; i < another.list.size(); i++){
            // Option 1: this.list.add(new AClass(another.list.get(i)));
            // problem: cannot instantiate AClass as it is abstract
            // Option 2: this.list.add(another.list.get(i).someKindOfClone());
            // problem? I'm thinking about it, seems to be what dasblinkenlight is suggesting below
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? It's easier to interpret the situation like that.

Comment: `AClass` is abstract. You cannot have instance of `AClass`

Comment: @Jimmy: someone other will instantiate a child of AClass and I need to provide a copy constructor for those unknown objects. I will show you some code in a while.

Comment: Jon Skeet is here. He can not miss it. You can accept below answer directly and then read it later ;)

Comment: "I'm thinking about it, seems to be what dasblinkenlight is suggesting below" Correct, that is precisely what I've suggested below :-)

Comment: You can implement your abstract class with empty anonymous class inside given loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I cannot create a copy constructor in `AClass` because it is an abstract class and I cannot know the name of the class which will inherit by `AClass`

This is generally correct. However, since you have a list of `AClass`, you do not need to know the exact subtype: an abstract function that make a copy would be sufficient:

```
protected abstract AClass makeCopy();
```

This is similar to the `clone()` function of the `java.lang.Object`, except all subclasses must implement it, and the return type is required to be `AClass`.

Since each subclass knows its own type, they should have no problem implementing `makeCopy()` method. Here is how this would look in your code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < another.list.size() ; i++) {
    this.list.add(another.list.get(i).makeCopy());
}
```

Note: this design is known as the [*prototype pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern), sometimes informally called the "virtual constructor".

Comment: I were to do such thing i would do this too, yes :) +1