# Copy-constructor for array of abstract pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, abstract-class

I'm making a copy-constructor in a class called `Registry`, which handles an array of pointers of the abstract class `Competitor`, while `Amateur` and `Professional` inherit from `Competitor`.

How would I go about transferring these to the array of the new Registry-object from the Registry-object I passed in to copy from?

Usually when I'm dealing with a concrete class I would make a for-loop and then do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
    this->arrOfComp[i] = new Competitor(*original.arrOfComp[i]);
```

Where `original` is a parameter of type `Competitor`.

But I can't allocate `Competitor` obviously now that it is abstract. And I don't know what type the next object in the array is, so I can't just change it to `... new Amateur(...)` or `... new Professional(...)`, they're not all the same, it's mixed; some are Amateurs, some are Professionals.

Is there some elegant way of making it transfer every object regardless of class so I don't have to write two if-statements and use typeid, dereferencing etc.?

And I know vectors might be the first thing that may come to your mind, but this is an assignment and I don't have a choice.

I checked this one:
[Copy constructor for abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844660/copy-constructor-for-abstract-class)

But it was about Java, I don't know how to make that for C++.

Comment: Not an array example but [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255546/c-deep-copying-a-base-class-pointer) is what you want.

Comment: Your `Competitor` class needs a (pure) virtual function, by convention called `clone`, that returns a pointer to a newly allocated copy of the object. Implement it in each child class.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading the linked question, will see if I have any questions after it.